# How to make a input space in vanilla html css and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to create an input space like the compose question input space of stackoverflow.

I have a blog. In the admin section of my blog I have a compose section. Now it only supports text and 1 paragraph. I want it to have the options to bold the text and make it italics or include some images by the user and also the support of multiple paras.

You can see a very good example of what I am trying to say in the stackoverflow's ask question section. The code should be in vanilla html, css and, js not react or any other framework.

I was not able to find anything over internet related to it.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: this is a relatively ambitious task for a beginner.  What have you tried? How many options do you want to provide?

Comment: Search for "javascript markdown editor" or similar. This topic is too broad for StackOverflow and usually not something that you implement yourself.

Comment: There are lots of rich text editors you can use that allow html formatting

Comment: You're going to have to make a section that will be on top of the input space. Like a navbar with the options you want and how you can change the text written to bold or italic. And handle these options with js.

Comment: Go with https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-5/demo/ - it's free if  up to 5 ppl. Or you can start developing your own. Thats just for a good start: https://www.thatsoftwaredude.com/content/8912/create-a-basic-text-editor-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

you can use a contenteditable element, see more at https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_contenteditable.asp

You can use ctrl+b, ctrl+u, ctrl+i, etc. to make it bold, underlined, and italicised. You can also use `document.execCommand()` (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_execcommand.asp) to create buttons that do this. `document.execCommand()` can change any CSS, so you can change size, color, bold, etc.

Comment: how does that help with changing the font-size or weight?

Comment: @DCR see my updated answer.